# check floppy Drive

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

To get the removable drives i have used **GetDriveType** ( ) function

Is it possible to check whether a drive is floppy drive or not ?

Please let me know your suggestions on this...

Thank you dor any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically differentiating between USB Floppy Drive and USB Flash Drive in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797128/programmatically-differentiating-between-usb-floppy-drive-and-usb-flash-drive-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, Microsoft Windows holds named characteristics flags (defined in wdm.h) for every device. If the device which corresponds the drive letter has flag `FILE_FLOPPY_DISKETTE`, then the drive is a floppy drive:

```
//
// Define the various device characteristics flags (defined in wdm.h)
//
#define FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA                    0x00000001
#define FILE_READ_ONLY_DEVICE                   0x00000002
#define FILE_FLOPPY_DISKETTE                    0x00000004
#define FILE_WRITE_ONCE_MEDIA                   0x00000008
#define FILE_REMOTE_DEVICE                      0x00000010
#define FILE_DEVICE_IS_MOUNTED                  0x00000020
#define FILE_VIRTUAL_VOLUME                     0x00000040
#define FILE_AUTOGENERATED_DEVICE_NAME          0x00000080
#define FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN                 0x00000100
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_PNP_DEVICE          0x00000800
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_TS_DEVICE           0x00001000
#define FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_WEBDAV_DEVICE       0x00002000
```

To get characteristics flags of a drive you can use different API functions. I find as a most effective and simple way to use `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` function from ntdll.dll. Under [Get information about disk drives result on windows7 - 32 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098696/how-to-get-the-vid-pid-and-drive-letter-for-all-the-usb-mass-storage-devices-plug/3100268#3100268) you will find an example of usage of this API.

**UPDATE:** You can use `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` function directly without previous calls of `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` and `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` which was called in the example for another reasons.

**UPDATED 2:** By the way the usage of `GetDriveType` to test if a drive is removeable is not safe. I have many removable hardware where `GetDriveType` show the drive as non removeable, but characteristics flags has do has `FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA` bit set. Usage of `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` with  `SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY` is also safe. In the last case you should test for  `CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_SURPRISE_REMOVAL` or `CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_ORDERLY_REMOVAL` like I do this in the example [Get information about disk drives result on windows7 - 32 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098696/how-to-get-the-vid-pid-and-drive-letter-for-all-the-usb-mass-storage-devices-plug/3100268#3100268).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible - have a look at the following [Microsoft Knowledge Base Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163920/en-us).

Comment: +1: I was just about to post the very same link ;) However, please note that this guaranteed only for Windows OSes up to Windows XP.

Answer (score -2):

The best chance that I know of is to check if the drive letter is A: or B:.  I haven't tried attaching three USB floppy drives to one PC so I don't know if a floppy might have a higher drive letter.  Other quirks are possible too.  But this test is nearly reliable enough for some purposes.

Comment: This is just wrong. I've seen many computers where `A:` was mapped to a network drive or even a real physical hard-drive.

Comment: This is bad advice - any type of drive can have any drive letter in Windows.

Comment: JBRWilkinson, it looks like you're right sometimes. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307844/en-us, "Drive letters A and B are reserved for floppy disk drives. However, if your computer does not have a floppy disk drive, you can assign these letters to removable drives." Oddly on my computers that don't have floppies Windows still reserved letters A and B for floppies, except when other quirks occured as mentioned in my posting.