# I'm using QDir().isReadable to check if a drive is readable. In the Qt Creator it runs fine, but when I run the exe it keeps giving me errors

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling, windows-7-x64

I'm using it like this:

```
if(QDir("G:/").isReadable()){
    qDebug("G Is readable!"); //Do something with G:/
}
```

As I said, in Qt Creator it runs fine without a problem, it checks if the drive is readable, and if so it prints it to the console, if not, it does nothing.

But when I run the .exe file, it keeps giving me errors each time it does the check (every 2 seconds) if the drive isn't readable.

"There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive G:."

I don't want this error to keep appearing, what do I do?

Edit: I think it's the isReadable function that causes the problem, is there any other way to do what I want to do? Or maybe should I write the code myself?

Comment: Is G: a mapped network drive? Those are per-session.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm not sure what a mapped network drive is, but I guess not. There is no G:/ normally, but it should and does appear when I plug in my android phone. Basically I'm checking if the phone is plugged in and the data from it is readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is generated by Windows.

There is a workaround for users that have applications that cannot be fixed. The error messages may be suppressed by setting `2` to registry key `ErrorMode` in:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL\MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows
```

It looks that if `QDir::isReadable()` is called after removing the media it triggers that error. `QDir::exists()` always returns `true` if the drive letter is present in the system, so it cannot be used here.

For now I see that it is possible to check removable media using native Windows API, see the answer to [How to detect if media is inserted into a removable drive/card reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158054/how-to-detect-if-media-is-inserted-into-a-removable-drive-card-reader)

The following code is able to detect that the media is removed without triggering the error:

```
#include <windows.h>

HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile (L"\\\\.\\G:",         // like "\\.\G:"
                             FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, // read access to the attributes
                             FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, // share mode
                             NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    // not valid device
    return;
}

WORD cbBytesReturned;
bool bSuccess = DeviceIoControl (hDevice,                // device to be queried
                            IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_VERIFY2,
                            NULL, 0,                     // no input buffer
                            NULL, 0,                     // no output buffer
                            (LPDWORD)&cbBytesReturned,   // # bytes returned
                            NULL);                       // synchronous I/O

CloseHandle(hDevice); // close handle

if (bSuccess && QDir("G:/").isReadable()) {
    // G is readable
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Just a minor correction, QDir::isReadable() triggers the error even if the device was never inserted in the first place.

I was thinking about calling QDir::exists() and if true call QDir::isReadable(), so it would check if the drive is readable only if it exists, i'll test and see what happens.

Comment: I tried, your solution works only until I insert a drive, then when I remove it the same error as before comes back. I guess that's just windows complaining about me disconnecting the drive while it is reading data? Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: @Metsuryu If the application reads the drive after `DeviceIoControl()` validation it is a problem. It is possible to change app error mode by `UINT oldMode = SetErrorMode( SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS );` Later if needed it is possible to restore error mode after that critical section `SetErrorMode(oldMode);`

Comment: It appears to be working, I'm going to test it some more and let you know, thanks so much.